# How to click a link using link text in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

Say I have these elements on my web page.

```
<a href="/dynamic1">One</a> 
<a href="/dynamic2">Two</a> 
<a href="/dynamic3">Three</a>
```

I want to click on the link with text `Two`. How to identify or click that element using the **Link Text** without any unique attributes like id or class.

In .Net I can use `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).click();`. What is the equivalent in nightwatch.js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The locator `By.linkText` uses an XPath internally.

So to click the second link from your example with an XPath :

```
.useXpath()     // every selector now must be XPath
.click("//a[text()='Two']")
.useCss()      // we're back to CSS now
```

Note that depending on the inner HTML, you may need to concatenate the children and trim the spaces:

```
.click("//a[normalize-space()='Some link']")
```

Comment: This seems surprisingly difficult for something that I assume would be used quite a lot? ... You know - find a link with the text 'ABC' and click it. Or is it just me?

Answer (score 6):

There is a better way now, you can use any of the documented [locator strategies](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#locator-strategies). Any one of; `id`, `css` `selector`, `link text`, `partial link text`, `tag name`, `xpath`.)

```
browser
  .click('link text', 'Some Link Text');
```

Answer (score 4):

The first param to `elements()` method is the *locator strategy*, use `link text` - it is supported:

```
client
  .url('http://website.org')
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
  .elements('link text', 'Two', function (result) {

    for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
      var element = result.value[i];

      // do something
    }
  })
  .end();
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way that worked for me was using:

```
.useXpath()
.click("//*[contains(text(), 'Two')]")
.useCss()
```