# Nightwatch.js: Click Text Link

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am trying to use Nightwatch to test the process of a user logging in using a log in text link. I checked out this: [How to click a link using link text in nightwatch.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538409/how-to-click-a-link-using-link-text-in-nightwatch-js) article which told me to use:

```
.useXpath()     // every selector now must be XPath
.click("//a[text()='Two']")
.useCss()      // we're back to CSS now
```

However that doesnt work.

The link I am trying to click is:

```
<li>
  <a href="/user/login">
      <strong>Sign in</strong>
  </a>
</li>
```

and I have tried:

```
.useXpath()
.click("a[text()='Sign in')]")
.useCss()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the error you get.

Answer (score 2):

I see // is missing in your  xpath locator

Try this

```
.useXpath()
.click("//a[text()='Sign in')]")
.useCss()
```